# How to disable kdeconnectd in OpenSUSE?

Tags: kde, opensuse

```
linux-4tur:~ # ss -tulpn|grep LISTEN
...
tcp    LISTEN     0      50       :::1716                 :::*                   users:(("kdeconnectd",pid=3395,fd=12))
...
linux-4tur:~ # 
linux-4tur:~ # grep 1716 /etc/services 
xmsg               1716/tcp     # xmsg  [Mark_E_Fogle]
xmsg               1716/udp     # xmsg  [Mark_E_Fogle]
linux-4tur:~ # 
linux-4tur:~ # ps -ef|grep -i kdeconnectd|grep -v grep
user      3395  3384  0 10:07 ?        00:00:08 /usr/lib64/libexec/kdeconnectd
linux-4tur:~ #
```

https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect#What_is_KDE_Connect.3F

I don't use this. But it listens on a port on all interfaces!

Q: How can I disable the kdeconnectd?

I tried to remove the kdeconnect-kde package, but if I do a "zypper up" after it, it reinstalls it, probably dependency..

I cannot see this as a separated service in systemctl. It is under "session-2.scope"

The binary is: /usr/lib64/libexec/kdeconnectd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude packages with this command:

```
sudo zypper addlock {package name}
```

So in your case it should look like this:

```
sudo zypper addlock kdeconnect-kde
```

Comment: first remove, then addlock, it worked! Thanks!